# What could be using an HTTP request method of "-"

Tags: apache-2.2, security

Got an apache log entry that looks like this, actually I have a bunch of them spread out over time.

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [27/Apr/2012:14:39:52 -0500] "-" 408 - "-" "-"
```

It wasn't a GET or POST, the method was "-".

Anyone else seen requests like this?  It wasn't from the penetration tester, but I have it from LOTS of other IPs from Apr of 2012 up until and including today.

We failed it with a 408, just wondering what someone might be trying and googling for minus sign does NOT work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

408 is Request Timeout. This means that the client connected but didn't actually send any data for a while, and the server gave up and dropped the connection with this error. This is also why nothing else was logged; no data was actually sent from the client.

[Apache's default timeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout) in this case is 300 seconds (5 minutes); it is configurable, but this generally shouldn't need to be changed.

Comment: I had just assumed 408 was one of the permission errors, but since its timed out, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

It means that Apache doesn't know what the request method is. In this case it was caused by a timeout (i.e. the client never sent a request). It's also common with 400 Bad Request responses where the client sends an invalid request (such as trying to speak TLS to a non-TLS port and vice versa), or closes the TCP connection as soon as it is establised without sending anything (such as monitoring services performing a TCP connection check).

Answer (score 1):

Could be caused by [slowloris](http://ha.ckers.org/slowloris/) or similiar attacks. The idea is to open as many connection as possible as long as possible. `Timeout` is by default 300 seconds [in Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout).

If you use a preforking server it's easy to reach `MaxClients` and make the website unaccessible. If the Apache is misconfigured lots of forked processing can cause excessive swapping and kill the machine or slowing it down to a crawl.

`mpm_event` or a good configured `mpm_worker` should be harder targets for slowloris. Other mitigations are reducing `Timeout` to a lower value. I guess it depends on your clients. You probably don't want to kill dail-up users with a time too low timeout. 5 minutes on the other hand is probably too much.